# Rotate google map marker image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker( 
{
    position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: { 
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
                    scale: 2,
                    rotation: degree   
                    }


        });
```

I am trying to rotate marker image on google map in some degree.

i am using above code it is nice but it is showing FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW by the code of                    **path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,**  but i want add a image here instead of arrow

such as car image so it can be rotate when vehicle move in some direction.  i have a degree of rotation so is there any way to put image instead of arraow

Answer (score -7, accepted):

try this

```
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker( 
{
    position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: { 
                    url: "/path/to/your/image.jpg",
                    scale: 2,
                    rotation: degree   
                    }


        });
```

Comment: sorry but this isn't the right answer , you should do some research before posting a answer

Comment: i used it already in my project

Comment: It doesn't work and Icon object does not have a rotation attribute

Answer (score 5):

You're using a [Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol) object for your icon in that example.  Instead you can use an [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) object.

```
icon: { 
     url: "/path/to/your/image.jpg"
}
```

It doesn't include a rotation attribute however.  Instead I'd assume you'd have multiple sprites, so you update that URL to use a particular image to represent different degrees of rotation, as required.  e.g. you could have them named like "image0.jpg", "image45.jpg" and "image90.jpg", etc.

Alternatively you could continue to use the Symbol object, but you can specify a path using [SVG path notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

Comment: thanks i already found it but my main aim is to rotate that icon image by some degree as i mentioned. actually i am using a car image  and i want to rotate that image in according direction.

Comment: did you guys find a solution other that declaring 360 images ?

Comment: Porbably the only solution which will work